# Batch variable updating

Tags: batch-file

Well, i have a weird script comportment and I am not sure what is going wrong. My script is only suppose to move all files from a folder and display their name (without extension). But the problem is that it always displays the previous file's name.

For Example I put the file test2.txt in the folder, run the script, put test1.txt, run the script it will give me test2 as answer.

Here's my script:

```
@echo off

for /r %%i in (*); do (

    MOVE /Y "%%i" C:\THEPATH 
    echo %%i

    For %%A in (%%i) do (
        echo %%A
        echo %%i
        set Name=%%~nA
        echo "TEST"
        echo %Name%
    )    
)
```

and the ouput :

1 fichier(s) déplacé(s).
x:\test3.txt
x:\test3.txt
x:\test3.txt
"TEST"
test123

test123 was the previous file. Why is the set not modifying the variable befor it gets displayed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [batch file fails to set variable in IF clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978088/batch-file-fails-to-set-variable-in-if-clause)

Answer (score 0):

Found an explanation right here http://www.robvanderwoude.com/variableexpansion.php. Seems that it's all interpreted like if the whole for line was written on the same line so you have to manually delay the variables to set them and use them within a FOR... Here's how I did it:

```
@echo off

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /r %%i in (*); do (

    MOVE /Y "%%i" C:\Users\xlaportf\Desktop\Updater\dist; 
    echo %%i 

    For %%A in ("%%i") do (       
        set Name=%%~nA      
    ) 

    echo !Name!
)
```

Answered my own question it seems anyway may be useful to someone!

Comment: The semicolons should be removed