# Problems reading simple numeric values from files in Windows batch files

Tags: windows, batch-file

My colleague and I have been pulling our hair out all day over this.

We have a simple Windows batch file.  We want it to read from a text file whose file path we are generating programmatically, take the single numeric value in this file, and compare it to a local variable.  But we're getting completely inexplicable behavior.

The file contains a single scalar number, such as the number 2. Here's the code:

```
ThisAppFlagFileName=foo.txt
if not exist "%HOMEPATH%\ourcompanyname\%ThisAppFlagFileName%" (
   ECHO do something here
) else (
    SET /P InstalledVersion=<"%HOMEPATH%\ourcompanyname\%ThisAppFlagFileName%"
    ECHO We think the file contains: %InstalledVersion%

    IF %InstalledVersion% GEQ %ThisVersionInstallDataNum% ( 
         ECHO Version %ThisVersion% of the %ThisAppVisibleName% has already been installed for this user; exiting.
         GOTO TheEnd
)
)

:TheEnd
Echo END
```

We keep getting an error reading `2 was unexpected at this time.`  So we inserted some trace message and, just in case the `else` was problematic, stuck to two different `if` statements:

```
ThisAppFlagFileName=foo.txt
if not exist "%HOMEPATH%\ourcompanyname\%ThisAppFlagFileName%" (
   ECHO do something here
)
ECHO Trace Message 1 before IF
if exist "%HOMEPATH%\ourcompanyname\%ThisAppFlagFileName%" (
    ECHO Trace Message 2 after IF before CD
    SET /P InstalledVersion=<%HOMEPATH%\ourcompanyname\%ThisAppFlagFileName%"
    ECHO We think the file contains: %InstalledVersion%

    IF %InstalledVersion2% GEQ %ThisVersionInstallDataNum% ( 
         ECHO Version %ThisVersion% of the %ThisAppVisibleName% has already been installed for this user; exiting.
         GOTO TheEnd
)
)

:TheEnd
Echo END
```

And we see *only* the first trace message (before the `if` statement), and *not* the second trace message.  So our conclusion is that somehow the *content* of the file is being interpolated into the line `if exist "%HOMEPATH%\ourcompanyname\%ThisAppFlagFileName%"`, but of course we don't understand why the first `if not exist` works but the second doesn't.

Can anyone spot the mistake, please?  Environment is Windows 7 `cmd.exe` window, but we are hoping to deploy to both Windows 7 and Windows XP.

Comment: You're not reading the content of the file at all. You're setting `InstalledVersion` to `<` plus the filename (`<%ThisAppFlagFileName%`). `<` does not redirect in a `SET` assignment. You need to use a `for /f` loop to actually read the content of the file. (You can confirm this from a command prompt - type `set something=<foo.txt` from a prompt in the folder where `foo.txt` is located, and then type `set something`.)

Comment: Apologies.  I forgot the /p switch.  I have edited the code.  Online references had indicated SET /p does accept <.  Will look up and try your approach.

Comment: `SET /P something=<foo.txt` (with an existing file, of course) results in "The system cannot find the file specified" (DOS error 2). I can't find any reference that says that `SET /P` accepts redirection, either.

Comment: @KenWhite - SET /P works with redirection, as does any command that reads stdin. But it only reads the first line of the file. The OP's file likely has many lines.

Comment: @dbenham: Can you cite a reference for that? It doesn't work here (Win7 64) in the quick tests I did before commenting.

Comment: @KenWhite - It works fine on my Win7 64 machine, as well as the many other Win platforms I have used it on **many** times. I'm not aware of any ref material that explicitly states what commands work with redirected stdin, nor would I expect to see it since it is the expected behavior based on the definition of redirected input. Go to any batch/"DOS" site and you will find many SET /P usage examples. However, SET /P does not give the desired result with piped input because both sides of the pipe are executed in a new CMD thread, so the assignment is lost as soon as the pipe thread terminates.

Comment: @dbenham: Ok.  Must be something I'm doing here. :-) Not important enough to me to investigate now (although I probably will at some point to figure out what I'm doing wrong), which is why I posted a comment and not an answer. :-)  I'm quite familiar with `SET /P`, BTW, but thanks for the suggestion that I investigate it. :-) I thought that what I said was that `SET /P` does not give the desired result with piped input, but perhaps I was mistaken.

Comment: FWIW, I see lots of references to `SET /P` accepting redirection.  See, e.g. (this thread)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068929/how-to-read-file-contents-into-a-variable-in-a-batch-file] .  But I also can't make it work, so I am now using the `FOR /F` approach, which is, at least, WORKING!  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that the entire IF expression is evaluated before the SET /P statement within it can be executed. InstalledVersion is not set yet, and so this invalid expression is evaluated:

```
IF GEQ 2 (
```

Nothing inside of the IF expression executes because it cannot be completely evaluated.

A solution is to enable [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) and replace %InstalledVersion% with !InstalledVersion!, as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978088/batch-file-fails-to-set-variable-in-if-clause.).

You can also restructure the code so the GEQ comparison happens after the IF expression.

Answer (score 2):

Your code have several errors. The first line:

```
ThisAppFlagFileName=foo.txt
```

missed a `set` command, so it is tryed to be executed as `ThisAppFlagFileName` command. This mean that `ThisAppFlagFileName` *variable* is NOT defined in your program, so `InstalledVersion` variable is never read from the file.

All references to `InstalledVersion` variable must use Delayed Expansion, that is, enclose they between exclamation marks instead percents and include `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` command at beginning of your program.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set ThisAppFlagFileName=foo.txt
if not exist "%HOMEPATH%\ourcompanyname\%ThisAppFlagFileName%" (
    ECHO do something here
) else (
    SET /P InstalledVersion=<"%HOMEPATH%\ourcompanyname\%ThisAppFlagFileName%"
    ECHO We think the file contains: !InstalledVersion!

    IF !InstalledVersion! GEQ %ThisVersionInstallDataNum% ( 
         ECHO Version %ThisVersion% of the %ThisAppVisibleName% has already been installed for this user; exiting.
         GOTO TheEnd
    )
)

:TheEnd
Echo END
```

You must be aware that all variables that are *modified inside parentheses* must also be enclosed in exclamation marks instead percent signs. Search for "delayed expansion" for details.

Comment: Thanks, AAcini!  The missing `set` was just a typo when transcribing to StackOverflow, but the other stuff makes perfect sense.  Thanks!